# Prove the following simple exponentiation equality.

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, exponentiation

Having trouble with the following proof.

Given $b > 1, c > 0$, prove that $ \exists \; x$ s.t. $b^{x} < c$.

We can't use $log$, and I have already shown that $b^{x} > c$ by using the formula $b^{n} - 1 = (b-1)(b^{n-1}+...+b+1)$.

I've been thinking of ways to manipulate the above formula, but having no luck.  I also thought about trying to use an epsilon delta limit proof, but in the end I would still need to use logs.  Any hints or ideas moving forward?

Comment: You can probably use the principles *behind* the logarithm without invoking the function.

Comment: You mean the taylor series representation for the log?

Comment: No, but if you can get $b^y > d$, then just set $y = -x$ and $c = 1/d$

Comment: ^ Makes sense.  Thanks Chaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what tools are allowed, so I will guess. Let $b=1+t$ where $t$ is positive. Then any positive integer $n$, by the *Bernoulli Inequality*, we have $(1+t)^n \ge 1+nt\gt nt$.

It follows that
$$b^{-n}=\frac{1}{(1+t)^n}\lt \frac{1}{nt}.$$
For suitable $n$, we have $\frac{1}{nt}\lt c$.

Comment: The Bernoulli Identity by the way comes directly from truncating the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: (+1) for the first sentence. Context was definitely not clear initially!